# Freestyle not rendering at all in copied scene (2.8). What am I missing?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, scene, freestyle

**What I want to do:** I would like to get started making some freestyle renders in Blender 2.8 and have been using a demo file from this site: [Blender demo files](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/). For a start, I would like to make a full copy of the scene and insert my own model instead of the sample.

**Problem:** However, in the full copy of the scene, the freestyle lines are not rendered. I can't upload the file here, but you should be able to reproduce the problem by downloading the demo file with the ATV buggy from the link above and make a full copy of the scene.

Does anybody know why this happens and what I can do to make it work?

Alternatively, I could setup freestyle rendering in my own blend file, but I haven't been able to make it work and I feel like something's missing, hence why I tried the demo file.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Freestyle are rendering settings saved at scene level. Copying and pasting objects doesn't transfer them

Comment: I copied (duplicated) the whole scene. So if freestyle settings are saved at scene level, surely they should be copied too?